# C#, how to generate new html Div during foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Depend of number of results I got like 3 results and I want to assign each result to label text and put to new Div each new line. How I do that?

`Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();` is where I stored results.

Here a sample C# codes,

```
foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
        {
            Label ipLabel = new Label();
            ipLabel.Text = psObject + "\r\n";
            div1.Controls.Add(ipLabel);
        }
```

Here a asp.net codes,

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

I got the right Label results but it all displayed in 1 div line instead of every div new line .

Comment: The `Repeater` control sounds like what you're looking for...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ideally, markup manipulation should be done using data-binding within your `.aspx` file rather than in your codebehind, but anyway:

```
foreach(PSObject psObject in output) {
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Controls.Add( new Label() { Text = psObject + "\r\n"; } );
    div1.Controls.Add( div );
}
```

This is how I would do it in the aspx file:

```
<div id="div1">
<% foreach(PSObject psObject in output) { %>
    <div>
    <%: psObject %>
    </div>
<% } //foreach %>
</div>
```

Note the use of `<%: foo %>` which is equivalent to `<%= Server.HtmlEncode( foo ) %>`.

Comment: @StudentIT "labels" don't exist in rendered HTML, the `id=""` attribute is applied to some other markup. Please explain what you ultimately want to accomplish.

Comment: I wanted to add textBox ID in `div.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "" });` empty textboxes during foreach loop because after user fill out name on each textbox, I want to be able to grab those specific textboxes to get values and pass back to server to update.

Comment: @StudentIT Using dynamically-created controls in ASP.NET WebForms is more complicated, you'll need to override the `CreateChildControls` method. The approach I put into my post is not suitable for adding input controls to a page, sorry.

Comment: It would appear that if you're trying to add an attribute like `<div id="someid" runat="server" some-attribute="<%: foo %>"></div>` you get `some-attribute="<%: foo %>"` in the HTML--only if you're placing it on another control. Why is that? Is there a way around that?

Comment: @codeMonkey You shouldn't ever get that: you'll get a compiler error (from the runtime compiler). Are you confusing `.aspx` with `.cshtml`?

Comment: Definitely `.aspx`. I have a situation where I am writing HTML inside a `foreach` loop. This works: `<td><%: foo %></td>` and this works `<img src="<%: foo %>" />` and this works `<td data-attribute="<%: foo %>"></td>` but this doesn't: `<td id="id" runat="server" data-attribute="<%: foo %>"></td>` and I'm wondering why and if there's a way to do that 

Comment: @codeMonkey there isn’t, because a `runat=“server”` control is not plaintext.

Answer (score 2):

The ["Panel"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control outputs a div, so maybe you'd like to wrap the Label there:

```
foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
{
    Panel ipPanel = new Panel();
    Label ipLabel = new Label();
    ipLabel.Text = psObject;
    ipPanel.Controls.Add(ipLabel);
    div1.Controls.Add(ipPanel);
}
```

You could also put a "
" (newline for HTML, roughly) inside the label:

```
foreach(PSObject psObject in output)
{
    Label ipLabel = new Label();
    ipLabel.Text = psObject + "<br/>";
    div1.Controls.Add(ipLabel);
}
```