# How to print the value which are present in an array from SQL SERVER database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database name "fees" where I have declared different columns tutionfee, computer fee, admissiofee etc.

I have retrieved the values of tutionfee to an array. So I can use it anywhere.

I want to print those values separately. How can I print. I am stuck with the problem

```
List<string> tutionfees = new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from fees where admno = @admno", conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admno", "admissionnumber.Text");
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                tutionfees.Add(rdr["tutionfee"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by print? Print to console with `Console.WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

After executing above code, you have `List<string> tutionfees.` 
You can print it as

```
foreach(String fee in tutionfees)
  Console.WriteLine(fee);
```

Or you can add above data to list control in Winform

```
foreach(String fee in tutionfees)
  ListBox1.Items.add(fee)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged ASP.NET, I assume you want to display it on a page of your ASP.NET web forms site.

This means you have to loop though the elements of the array in your view and output the items in, for example, an unordered list of whatever layout you want it to have. Or you can do it in the code behind.

Here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105525/c-how-to-generate-new-html-div-during-foreach-loop) about it.